# jira python oauth: how to get the parameters for authentication?

Tags: python, oauth, jira

I am trying to use oauth to access jira, and I am reading this document: [Welcome to jira-python's documentation](http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#oauth).

But in this oauth part, I cannot figure out how I can get these parameters:

`access_token, access_token_secret, consumer_key, key_cert`

Comment: Link 'http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#oauth' is dead (404)

Answer (score 13):

I too am using jira-python. Since jira-python uses [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [requests-oauthlib](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) I used those same libraries to implement the OAuth 1 dance necessary to get the tokens.

First, setup JIRA:

1. Generate RSA public/private key pair (you end up with `rsa.pub` and `rsa.pem` files). Your Python code will need access to the private key `rsa.pem`.
2. Configure a JIRA application (done in JIRA admin under "Application Links") with "Incoming Authentication" and use the public key generated above. This is where you specify the `consumer_key` needed by jira-python

Next, the OAuth dance. It's pretty simple with `OAuth1Session` from [requests-oauthlib](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). Here is a simple example (CLI): [JIRA Oauth in Python](https://bitbucket.org/MicahCarrick/atlassian-oauth-examples/src/68d005311b9b74d6a85787bb87ccc948766486d3/python-requests/).

The workflow is described in the [requests-oauthlib](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) docs: [OAuth 1 Workflow](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth1_workflow.html).

So, to summarize:

- access_token - Obtained at the end of the OAuth 1 Workflow.
- access_token_secret - Obtained at the end of the OAuth 1 Workflow.
- consumer_key - Specified when you setup an "Application Link" in JIRA admin.
- key_cert - The contents of the `rsa.pem` file (private key). The public key is also added when setting up the "Application Link" in JIRA admin.

Comment: Worked! To help if someone have problems, use this to change the script suggested on this answer: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/VerifierMissing-exception-while-doing-Oauth-authentication-with/qaq-p/481575

Comment: How to generate RSA key pair ?

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-generate-public-key-to-application-link-3rd-party-applications-913214098.html

Answer (score 3):

First you need to add an application link to JIRA for your application: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA060/Configuring+Application+Links

For the case when the application accessing JIRA is not a web application, you can use arbitrary URL as the application URL, but that url will be used to retrieve the application icon when it's displayed in the list of Application Links in administrative UI of JIRA.

Then you would need to do a so called "oauth dance" to get an OAuth token and its corresponding secret. Please take a look at Atlassian examples here: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/atlassian-oauth-examples/src

Those examples are mostly covering the dance itself, while the authentication using OAuth token+secret (which is received during the dance) is documented here: http://jira.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#oauth. I hope this helps.

At least it worked for me (also in Python for my case). :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, other answers don't work with Python 3. I found that https://github.com/rkadam/jira-oauth-generator fully covers Jira OAuth in Python 3.